# How to compute the minimum number of rectangles required to cover occupied cells in a grid?

Tags: algorithm

Given an *R*×*C* grid, out of which certain cells are occupied, what is the minimum number of rectangles needed to cover the occupied cells?

- Each rectangle is either *R*×1 or 1×*C*.
- Rectangles can overlap.
- Occupied cells can be covered more than one rectangle.

**Example:**

```
x - - - -
- - x - -
- x - x x
x - x - -
```

Here `x` and `-` mark occupied and unoccupied cells, respectively.

The minimum number of rectangles necessary in this case is 3. (Cover column 1, column 2, and row 3.)

Can anyone point me to the right direction? This seems easy enough, but I’m not able to arrive at a robust solution!

Comment: Look at the Hungarian Algorithm for solving assignment problems. This constitutes a part of that algorithm. Minimum number of lines required to cover all the zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a bipartite graph consisting of two sets of vertices, with the vertices in the first set corresponding to the rows, and the vertices from the second set corresponding to the columns of the grid. A vertex *i* from the first set is connected to a vertex *j* from the second set iff `a[i][j] == 'x'`.

Then the problem is reduced to finding a [minimum vertex cover](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimumVertexCover.html) of this graph, i.e., the smallest set of vertices such that each edge of the graph has at least one of its endpoints present in this set. As the graph is bipartite, a minimum vertex cover can be computed in polynomial time; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449554/find-minimum-vertex-cover-for-bipartite-graph-given-the-maximum-matching).