# Algorithm to find the minimum number of shots required to erase dots in a grid

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I saw this programming puzzle on a website and tried to solve it.

PROBLEM

You are given a N x N grid in which there are certain dots randomly distributed.You have to remove the dots by using the following allowed actions

- You can either remove all the dots in a row with a single shot
- Or you can remove all the dots in a column with a single shot.

You have to find the minimum number of shots required to remove all the dots.

Example

In the following grid,you need three shots- one horizontal and two vertical to remove the dots.

[image]

I tried one approach as counting the rows and columns with the dots and whichever was minimum would be the answer.But it fails in specific cases like in the example above.
What is the way to do it or is there any situation analogous to it which I can refer to solve this problem?

**EDIT**

The constraints given are

```
1 <= N <= 1000
0 <= x,y <= 10^9
Time Limit: 2 sec
```

where n is dimension of grid (i.e. nxn) and x,y are the coordinates

Comment: I guess, throw each shot per column is the best solution I can get. At worst case, it's O(N) and for any other solution it will be the worst case where all dots are arranged diagonally or where complete matrix is filled up with dots

Comment: @Reddy :But if you go by throwing one shot for each column then it will give wrong answer as 6 for the above example given.Though the correct answer is 3

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208218/minimum-rectangles-required-to-cover-occupied-cells-in-a-grid/19208449#19208449

Comment: @Insane Coder, sorry I missed the question bit

Comment: @EvgenyShavlyugin : Thanks for pointing.But even that problem is not answered well for 2 days now

Comment: @InsaneCoder, what about my answer to that? Zero score doesn't mean that solution is incorrect. In fact, it's a classical problem of finding minimal vertex cover in bipartite graph.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, it's NP complete in arbitrary graphs. As said in algorithm section of wiki article, for bipartite graphs Hopcroft-Karp maximal matching algorithm can be easily adapted for vertex cover. For detailed description of algorithm see http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs261/lecture14.pdf

Comment: Exact duplicate of running CodeChef's challenge ["Kamehameha"](http://www.codechef.com/OCT13/problems/KMHAMHA).

Comment: I have found out the solution.I used two linked lists- one for storing points according to x- coordinate and another according to y-coordinate.Each node in the first linked list keeps a record of x-coordinate ,say 1,and count of points with same x-coordinate.Similarly in other LL for y-coordinate.The LL are descending LL.Now,I compare the first nodes of both linked lists,whichever is maximum I delete that node and increase count by 1 and keep repeating this procedure until both are not empty.
At the end,value of count will give the minimum shots.

Answer (score 1):

Transform the 2D grid to be a bipartite graph. The left side contains nodes represent row and the right side contains nodes represent column. For each cell containing dot, suppose it's coordinate is (x,y), add an edge linking row_x and column_y. After the bipartite graph is established, use Hungarian algorithm to get the maximum matching. Since in bipartite graph, the answer of maximum matching equals minimum vertex covering, that's exactly what you want.

The Hungarian algorithm is a O(V*E) algorithm. For more details, pls refer to [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)

For more information about bipartite graph, pls refer to [Bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), you can find why maximum matching equals minimum vertex covering here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try an exhaustive algorithm. It's not as bad as it sounds if you do it right.

You already know that in the worst case it will take N shots (if you shoot at every row, or every column, it will work for sure).

So to improve on the worse case, you only need to try all permutations of possible column shots + row shots, where the total number of shots is less than N.  For example, if N=4, non-trivial solutions must be <= 3, so try all of (column, row) shots:

```
(0,3)
(1,2)
(2,1)
(3,0)
```

For any axis (column or row) where you want to take s shots, there are `(s choose N)` possibilities.  So the total number of possibilities for large N is something like `(N/2) choose N` which isn't too bad for N < 30 anyway.

I'm sure there's a better heuristic, and there may be a better worse case algorithm as well.

Comment: But the input domain can have upto 1000 x 1000 size, hence need a more optimised solution.

Comment: Then I would look very carefully at how a solution to size `N` applies to the solution for size `N + 1`. Ideally, you can reuse most of the state and reduce the complexity of calculation dramatically.

Comment: @Evgeny Shavlyugin got it the questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think recursion maybe applied here. I don't think it is efficient but following is an idea that you can use.

Start with the left - topmost dot. You have following scenarios:

1. There is another dot in same row and same column. -> branch out to three possibilities
2. There is another dot in same row but not in same column. -> Shoot this row, remove all dots in same row and move onto next dot.
3. There is another dot in same column but not in same row.-> Shoot this column, remove all dots in same column and move onto next dot.
4. There is no dot in either the same column or the same row. -> shoot either row or column, it does not matter and proceed to next dot.

For the 1st case, the branching shall have to be done something like the following:

```
int minimumNumberOfLines( matrixOfDots ) {
  return min( 1 + minimumNumberOfLines( with row shot ),1 + minimumNumberOfLines( with col shot ), 2 + minimumNumberOfLines( with row and column shot ) ). 
}
```

Comment: It will cause time limit exceeded if all grids contain dot. It's about O(3^n), which is surely unacceptable.